# Flutter: I am getting errors after downgrading my Flutter version to 2.5.0

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

So I have decided to downgrade my Flutter version from **3.0.5** to **2.5.0** using `git checkout 2.5.0`, and have been getting some errors that I cannot fix. I want this project to run on **2.5.0**. How can I solve those errors so I can run my project on version **2.5.0**?

**The errors:**

```
../../../Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-4.2.1/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:162:5: Warning: The class 'WidgetsBinding' cannot be null.
Try replacing '?.' with '.'
    WidgetsBinding?.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:11: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:16:9: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:11:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^
../../../Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^
```

**pubspec.yaml file:**

```
environment:


sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"


 
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 
  cupertino_icons: null
  firebase_auth: 
  firebase_core: 
  firebase_messaging: 
  flutter_google_places: null
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  geocoder: 
  geoflutterfire: 
  geolocator: 
  google_maps_flutter: null
  google_maps_webservice: null
  http: null
  location: ^4.4.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.1
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.1
  provider: null
  rxdart: any
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  uuid: null
  url_launcher: ^6.0.5
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  plugin_platform_interface: 
  geolocator_platform_interface: 
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  google_api_availability:
  google_api_headers: ^1.1.1
  mockito: ^5.2.0
```

Comment: May I ask why you downgraded?

Comment: Trouble with connecting my project to the android emulator. I saw a post with a similar problem that happened only after updating Flutter from 2.2.0 to 2.10.0

Comment: Then I recommend that you post a question about the emulator connection problem and get that fixed. Downgrading will cause many problems, and you will have to upgrade at some point.

Comment: Yeah. done that enough. No response.

Comment: You are going down the wrong road downgrading to try and fix the emulator issue, trust me. Good luck.